# Has the NSIS execution level requirements changed for Windows 7?

Tags: permissions, installation, directory, nsis, windows-update

I have a .nsi file I use to create my installation exe. I had given my file the follow execution level in the past (and it worked successfully):

```
RequestExecutionLevel user
```

This was so that it could be installed as a local user version or by admin on all accounts.

I was recently releasing another file with the same layout (i.e. copy files to install folder/create start menu short cut/HKCU register for install) it now requires `RequestExecutionLevel` to be set to `admin` or `highest`. When I checked with my other installer I found this was the case there as well now.

> Why does my installer NOW require a higher execution level?
>
> Has a recent windows update changed the RequestExecutionLevel required?

Comment: What are you trying to say? Writing to HKCU does not require `RequestExecutionLevel admin`.

Answer (score 1):

The `RequestExecutionLevel` NSIS attribute just sets the [RequestedExecutionLevel](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb756929.aspx) node in the manifest and should work exactly the same in 7, 8 and 10 so there must be something else going on.

Have you tried watching the installer with [Process Monitor](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896645.aspx) to verify that you are writing to the correct location?